# How to fetch user created Group information using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

How we can find user created groups following attributes using Google apps Script.
1. Group Creation Time(Group created by user) 
2. Posting permission Change by user (Name or ID).

Comment: You can use same code to fetch all domain group list.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784889/how-to-get-the-list-of-members-in-a-google-group-in-google-app-script-admin-sdk/39570052#39570052

Answer (score 2):

In the Reports API you can get the activities related to groups.
There are many events for groups described [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/groups-event-names).

You can also get an example of how to call this api from apps script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, its useful link