# How to get the list of members in a Google group in Google app script (Admin SDK)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups-api, google-admin-sdk

I would like to get a list of members in a Google group using Admin SDK.

But im not getting how to do this. I found below link - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members

But I do not know how to use POST method in Google app script.

Can someone please guide me with an example?

**UPDATED**

I got the output as below, But i would like to access each element (role,email) separately for each member of the group. Is that possible??

`{
    "role": "OWNER",
    "kind": "admin#directory#member",
    "type": "USER",
    "etag": "\"fdo0/1gUrEe8bli75zvzmqFHyH3cPzlQ\"",
    "id": "107108832717913338955",
    "email": "useremailid@domain.com",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  }`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help by telling us which programming language you are using or which platform.

Comment: I am writing in Google App script

Comment: can you share the app script code ? what is your goal here reading members of a Google group or manage the members ?

Comment: Are you also a administrator for your Google Apps Domain ? you need be  Google Apps domain admin to use admin SDK ?

Comment: Yes..i do have super admin access to the domain..i just want to read the members in a Google group and then update them if needed

Answer (score 5):

Please follow the steps,

1. Login your G drive using super admin account.
2. Create one Google sheet.
3. Go to sheet Tool menu -- script Editor..  Save Script project project. **Enable admin SDK**
4. Apps script editor click on **Resources** menu select **Advance Google Services** -- In Pop up on Admin Directory Apis then Click **Google Developers Console** link. 
   Developer Console -- click on Library --> search APIs box enter Admin sdk --> click on admin Sdk api link ==> **ENABLE** and close dev console.

=== At Apps script editor paste following code.

```
var onSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var groupKey = "googlegroupid@domainName.com"

function MainGetUserList()
{
    var rows = [];
    var pageToken, page;
    do {
        page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupKey,
        {
            domainName: 'YOURDOMAINNAME.@com',
            maxResults: 500,
            pageToken: pageToken,
        });
        var members = page.members
        if (members)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
            {
                var member = members[i];
                var row = [groupKey, member.email, member.role, member.status];
                rows.push(row);
            }
        }
        pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    } while (pageToken);
    if (rows.length > 1)
    {
        var sheetData = onSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
        var header = ['Group Name', 'User Id', 'User role', 'User Status'];
        sheetData.clear()
        sheetData.appendRow(header).setFrozenRows(1);
        sheetData.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, header.length).setValues(rows);
    }
}
```

==> Run MainGetUserList() function allow the permission, open you Google Sheet refresh it.

Done.

I have tested this 20k members.
Thanks

Comment: Also I have one more query.,Is it possible to get the list of groups in which I have manager or owner access?

I mean , If I enter my email id , It should display all the group email id's in which I have manager or owner role

Comment: currently no direct method available to for this but using user email id you can find this user total groups membership

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the reply anyway..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Members:list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) to retrive list of all members in a group.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members
```

Every request your application sends to the Directory API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) to authorize requests.

**HTTP response:**

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#members",
  "etag": etag,
  "members": [
    members Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```